# In C#, is accessing the current object's properties through this.XYZ considered poor style compared to just XYZ

Tags: c#, coding-style

Is it a simple case of just never using the this.XYZ construct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's only considered poor style if it violates your style guidelines. Sometimes using `this` is necessary to qualify a member variable over a local variable:

```
public MyType(int arg)
{
    this.arg = arg;
}
```

This problem can also be mitigated with style guidelines. For example, prefix members with "_":

```
public MyType(int arg)
{
    _arg = arg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it's poor style - but it's not particularly idiomatic.

My almost sole use of `this.foo` is when copying parameters into fields:

```
public Person (string name, string occupation)
{
   this.name = name;
   this.occupation = occupation;
}
```

Comment: You don't preface your fields with underscores?

Comment: Nope. I never have in my personal code. I've worked at places which do, and I've worked at places which don't. I don't care much any more. What scares me is that I just subconsciously used "brace at end of line" which is the Google style rather than my personal style. Editing...

Comment: in general, (except for in initializers - cctors) I always set the public properties, not the private fields, in constructors... so the ctor parameter is lowerCase, and the property is UpperCase... (no need for this.)

   Name = name;

Comment: Charles: That doesn't work when the field is readonly so the property has no setter...

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of it being a style issue.  I used to do it all the time to get intellisense, but then I started using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd>, then I just found myself remembering my object's properties without having to use a crutch.

Probably because my objects have become less complex as I gain more experience...

Answer (score 1):

I always use this. for global variable. This way, I can clearly know that I am using a global variable without having to use prefix like "_".

Comment: Yes, because it's so much easier to prefix with "this." than with "_"  ;)

Comment: well, it's clearer in my opinion. And the Intellisense is there... it's part of the Framework.. so why not.

Comment: I have to add that if you do it all the time and not only for parameter passing to global than it's become easy to follow a code because it's always the same. not "sometime" it's used for global and some time not... but it's just my opinion.

Comment: Yep, makes sense. I haven't yet worked on a project that required prefixing with "this." so don't have any experience having to do so on a regular basis. Was just poking fun...

Comment: No problem, I think it's really just an opinion and they aren't any good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The MS tool StyleCop insists on the this.XYZ (or should that be this.Xyz) variant when analysing source code.

Comment: That's just based on its default rules. You can customize the rules to suit your organization or team.